# Drupal. Исполнение функции после ahah запроса

Tags: drupal

Кусок формы:

```
'#disabled_options' => array(6),
    '#ahah' => array(
        'event' => 'change',
        'path' => 'custom/js',
        'wrapper' => 'ownquestion',
        'method' => 'replace',
        'progress' => array('type' => 'throbber'),
    )
```

При выборе определенного пункта в `<SELECT` запускает AHAH функцию, вставляя в `<div>` с айдишником *ownquestion* определенный кусок формы(текстовый инпут).

Задача сразу установить на этом инпуте фокус. Пробовал тупо создать событие onchange в jsнике, но он, зараза, естественно срабатывает ДО асинхронного запроса.
Как его заставить сработать после?

Аналог в jquery:

```
$('#myId').change(function(){
    $.post('myurl.php',{/*params*/},function(data){
        /*обработка пришедшей инфы и навешивание плюшек*/
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел.

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function()
    {
        //Запускаем исполнение кода.
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Это, конечно, костыль, но буржуи на форумах пишут, что более человеческих методов не существует.